# Suggestions for latest ESP8266 WiFi module

Tags: esp8266

I am having problems with the ESP8266-01 I bought. It works at only 115200 baud rate and it gives many problems when programming with Arduino Uno. I got it flashed to 9600 baud rate, but still many times it becomes unreliable.

I have seen many videos online that has the ESP8266 that works at 9600 by default.

Could someone please tell me where I can buy the latest ESP8266 that runs at 9600 baud rate by default?

Answer (score 1):

No, I'm afraid we can't, since we're not ESP8266 salesmen.

However, I would seriously recommend not using an Arduino to communicate with the ESP8266 but instead to program the ESP8266 directly so you don't have any communication worries.  If you want to add an Arduino into the mix at a later date for its enhanced IO capabilities, then feel free to do so - where you can then implement your own serial protocol at whatever baud rate you like (or other protocol even - SPI? I2C?).

All you need is:

- The Arduino core for the ESP8266: https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino
- Some form of USB serial adapter (eg FT232 breakout board).

The controller chip on the ESP8266 is considerably more powerful than the Arduino's chip, and the fact that many people insist on using the ESP8266 as a slave device to the lower powered Arduino always seems completely backward to me.

If you want an easier board to program that messing with breakout boards you can do a lot worse than investing in a NodeMCU board. Make sure you go for the version 1 not the version 0.9 since the version 1 has a slightly more enhanced chip on it with more IO facilities than the version 0.9.

Comment: Thank you @majenko. But I m not that much of an electrical guy. I want to do a project on home automation. I learned to control the relays using arduino. Now I want to control my arduino remotely so that I could control relays with arduino easily. That's why I am using esp8266 with arduino. But I am having lot of problems with baud rate and serialsoftware. Could you please give me a solution for this?

Comment: Or could you provide me a link where I could download the latest firmware of esp8266 and flash it to use at 9600 baud rate easily

Comment: I have. Ditch the Arduino and get a NodeMCU. With the Arduino core installed it's exactly like working with the Arduino. Same language. Just a lot easier to work with for WiFi.

Comment: My mom will burn me. I bought lot of electronic equipments online. Or could you give me link of the latest firmware bin file for esp8266. Please. @majenko

Comment: I don't know a link for that kind of thing. This is an Arduino site not an ESP8266 site. Maybe you should ask for that link on an ESP8266 site, or ask google for it.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. @majenko. I will try my best.

Comment: The ESP8266 has 3 SPI slave selects, but note that one of them is used for the off-board flash that contains the firmware, and not all modules make SPI available externally. UART is the way to go, since it is available on most if not all modules.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I use my ICSC library on the ESP modules for serial communication. Works well and is very easy to use.

Comment: @Majenko I think often Arduino is used as master because it has lower power consumption in the lowest sleep modes: it can send ESP8266 into the power down most of the time, and therefore save battery. For example https://openhomeautomation.net/esp8266-battery/ If you have only ESP8266, can you wake it up from deepsleep from the uploaded firmware?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the other bit of it that most people don't understand on their first try.

Everything that plugs into an arduino is not a slave device.

In this case both this module and the hc-05 and hc-06 are standalone and actually **HAVE THEIR OWN SOFTWARE** on them. These chips are fully functional without arduino and you can send commands to them directly or by using the arduino as a dummy chip.

So at the end of the day to get your project working you should interface with the device directly instead of passing it through arduino.

Your device most likely isn't busted so don't worry about constantly flashing between versions. You probably just need to configure it using AT+ commands.

Here is a pdf of AT+ commands
[Download pdf](https://www.google.com/urlhttps://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://rancidbacon.com/files/kiwicon8/ESP8266_WiFi_Module_Quick_Start_Guide_v_1.0.4.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjXmJWb_bXJAhVHKCYKHR6gDcIQFggcMAE&usg=AFQjCNGkMIRnc2C3uzlIlXCZ1seaiRgXmQ&sig2=AAPvKqWZl44dDPV86lzxUA)

This is a quickstart guide that includes pictures and order of commands. Don't fry your boards.

[Download pdf](https://www.google.com/urlhttps://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://rancidbacon.com/files/kiwicon8/ESP8266_WiFi_Module_Quick_Start_Guide_v_1.0.4.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjXmJWb_bXJAhVHKCYKHR6gDcIQFggcMAE&usg=AFQjCNGkMIRnc2C3uzlIlXCZ1seaiRgXmQ&sig2=AAPvKqWZl44dDPV86lzxUA)

After that's done serialCommand amd software serial are pretty easy to use. Look at the serialCommand examples to see how it's done.

[SoftwareSerial example using serialCommand](https://github.com/scogswell/ArduinoSerialCommand/tree/master/examples/SerialCommandExampleSoftwareSerial)

Comment: The problem is that you need another device to send the AT commands, and they need to be sent each time the device is powered on. This is why reprogramming the device to work completely standalone is a better solution.

Comment: Why do they need to be sent every time? Shouldn't it be able to function on it's own from stock? the whole point behind AT commands is that you can initialize it so it can function as needed, and not need to set things such as the baud rate and the name every time it's reset.

Comment: If I'm wrong that's fine, I just don't understand why you would need to do that every time. I have worked on other AT devices like bluetooth and it seems to hold up just fine after initialization.

Comment: Those devices have a firmware which is programmed to store settings on the module itself. The AT firmware for the ESP8266 for the most part is not.

Comment: Looks like I'm going to toy with it this week. I'll get back to you